# TwitterOAuth get friends confusion

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using Abraham's twitteroauth class and after authenticating a user I'm trying to grab a list of ids the user is following.

Authentication works fine because I can run:

```
$user = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

And get the required result. So according to the **test.php** file on Github's twitteroauth I should also be able to run the following:

```
$friends = $connection->get('statuses/friends');
```

But if I var_dump the output I get the following:

```
stdClass Object( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Sorry, that page does not exist [code] => 34 ) ))
```

The "statuses/friends" seems to be the wrong request, so could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Should have read a bit further. The answer is to go for:

```
$friends = $connection->get('friends/ids');
```